# sql group by 2 field count?

Tags: mysql, database

`name   status
a       win
a       run
a       run
b       run
b       win
b       win
c       run
c       run
c       run
d       run
d       run
e       NA
e       run
e       win
f       NA
f       NA
f       NA`

in mysql

**here I need to take the count of run also not win same for win and NA**

can anyone help me out?

EXPECTED OUTPUT

`WIN  3
RUN  2
NA   1`

TRIED qUERY
`SELECT a
FROM data
GROUP BY a
HAVING ( COUNT(*) > 1 )`

Comment: Can you show us the expected output?  Have you tried writing a query yet?  The best way to learn SQL is to spend time actually using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    name,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'win' THEN 1 END) AS WIN,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'run' THEN 1 END) AS run,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'NA'  THEN 1 END) AS NA
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    name;
```